# Relation to FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

How can I create a relation with FOSUserBundle? FOS is working good in my project. Now I create my bundle `NewsBundle`. In `NewsBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/News.orm.yml` I enter:

```
Josh\NewsBundle\Entity\News:
    type: entity
    table: news
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    manyToOne:
        user:
            targetEntity: FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User
            inversedBy: news
            joinColumn:
                name: user_id
                referencedColumnName: id
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 100
```

And I generate entities (without errors) and I try `doctrine:schema:update` and I get this error:

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
Column name `id` referenced for relation from Josh\NewsBundle\Entity\News towards FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User does not exist.
```

How can I create a relation to User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own User entity who extends Fos\UserBundle\Model\User...    That's how I done...

Comment: Is somewhere a tutorial for this?

Comment: Yes, lol, in the documentation of this bundle : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: Yes, now i dont have errors, but relation with user_id not exists. This created field user_id in table news, but without relation to fos_user_user.

Comment: Now your user entity is not fosuser.  The target entity is YourNewUserEntity. You don't have to touch to the fosuser entity anymore now.